# Javascript form validation, showing error message next to <input>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and HTML and am trying to do some form validation.  When the validation() fails for some input like

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" />
```

I'd like to have an error message show next to the field that was in error.  How do I find the location of where to put the message?  Or do I have some sort of label that's hidden to set when there is an error?  Thanks.

Comment: Why not use jQuery [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a div tag such as `<div id="errorMsg"></div>`, and in your javascript, when validation fails, use:

```
document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML = "error msg";
```